# Datatables load records per page in real time

Tags: jquery, datatables, pagination

I have the plugin datatables 1.10 and I am trying to reduce the loading times, I currently have more than 1000 records that have to be shown in the table, and I have it configured to be paginated.

The problem is that when you load the page what you do is load all the records and once loaded it shows all the content and the page, I have since per page it shows 6 records.

What I want or would like is that when I load the page I only have to load the records of the current page, if I have to load the next page, then I would load the records of the page again.

I tried with "serverSide: true," but what it does is load them all without pagination.

This is my code actually:

```
var showcontent = baseurl+"transaction/showcontent";
var table = $('#datatablecontent').DataTable({
"responsive": true,
"processing": true,
    "lengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, -1], [10, 25, 50, "Todos"]],
    "ajax": {
        "url": showcontent,
        "type": "POST"
},        
"autoWidth": false,
'columnDefs': [
  { 'width': 10, 'targets': 1 },
  { 'width': 5, 'targets': 2 },
  { 'width': 5, 'targets': 3 },
  { 'width': 5, 'targets': 4 },
  { 'width': 55, 'targets': 5 },
  { 'width': 30, 'targets': 6 },
  { 'width': 20, 'targets': 7 },
  { 'width': 20, 'targets': 8 , 'visible': false},
  { 'width': 40, 'targets': 9 },
  { 'width': 20, 'targets': 10 , 'visible': false},
  { 'width': 20, 'targets': 11 , 'visible': false},
  { 'width': 20, 'targets': 12 , 'visible': false},
  { 'width': 20, 'targets': 13 },
  { 'width': 20, 'targets': 14 },
  { 'width': 10, 'targets': 15 },
  { 'width': 20, 'targets': 16 , 'visible': false},
  { 'width': 10, 'targets': 17 },
  { 'width': 10, 'targets': 18 },
  { 'width': 10, 'targets': 19 },
  { 'width': 10, 'targets': 20 , 'visible': false},
  { 'width': 10, 'targets': 21 , 'visible': false},
  { 'width': 50, 'targets': 22 },
  { 'targets': 0,'searchable':false,'orderable':false,}
  //{ 'targets': 1,'searchable':false,'orderable':false,}
],
"fixedColumns": true,
"iDisplayLength": 5,
"order": [[ 2, "desc" ]]
});

File php/codeigniter: transaction(controller)
public function showcontent(){
...
//Here before is the code from send data json
$output = array(
              "data" => $data,
  );
echo json_encode($output);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use server-side script that will paginate results in addition to enabling server-side processing mode with `serverSide: true`.

With PHP you can use `ssp.class.php` that is available in `/examples/server_side/scripts` folder when you [download DataTables library](https://datatables.net/download/download).

There is also a sample script `server_processing.php` in `/examples/server_side/scripts` folder that shows how to use it.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but as I said in the first message, I have already tried to put "serverSide: true" and it shows all the content at once and does not show the page.

Comment: @Sylar, please re-read my answer. In addition to using `serverSide: true` you need to paginate your results on the server-side with PHP. Currently you are out printing out all of your data with `echo json_encode($output);`.

Comment: Yes, I understand, I have downloaded the file you comment, but I have not been able to see where the code is to assemble the pagination. The strange thing is that if I don't put the option of "serverSide: true" the pagination does appear.

In this example, the content is loaded when the scroll bar is moved, I want me to do something very similar but with pagination, and to load the content of the server when it is clicked on each page:
https://datatables.net/extensions/scroller/examples/initialisation/server-side_processing.html